# ListView - Scroll to specific item

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="LvLevels" 
                  Margin="10 60 0 0" 
                  SelectionChanged="LvLevels_SelectionChanged">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>

                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="6">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                   FontSize="56" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                                   Margin="10"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   TextAlignment="Center">


                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I need to select specific Item and scroll ListView to it.  I can select Item:

```
LvLevels.SelectedItem = CurrentLevel;
```

But I cannot to scroll ListView to this item.  Here is my code:

```
LvLevels.ScrollIntoView(LvLevels.SelectedItem);
```

I have created demo-example [here](https://github.com/demas/listview_example).

Here is a [code](https://github.com/demas/listview_example/blob/master/App6/MainPage.xaml.cs) which set DataContext and set Selected Item:

```
        List<int> data = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            data.Add(i);

        LvLevels.DataContext = data;

        LvLevels.SelectedItem = LvLevels.Items[14];
        LvLevels.ScrollIntoView(LvLevels.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is caused by this line:

```
LvLevels.SelectedItem = CurrentLevel;
```

Instead of that line, use something like this line to test with:

```
LvLevels.SelectedItem = LvLevels.Items[4];
```

The point is that you can only set the `SelectedItem` to an *actual* item from the collection that is data bound to the `ListView.ItemsSource` property. Once you have done that, the call to `LvLevels.ScrollIntoView` should work just fine.

Comment: It doesn't help me.  I have created little demo example https://github.com/demas/listview_example and updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not interested in loading up solutions from complete strangers. Instead of that, try changing your `int` collection to a custom class type. If you the select an item from code behind and call `ScrollIntoView` then you'll see that it *does* work... I tested it to be double sure.

Comment: I don't offer to loading up solution. You can only look at the code on the browser. Anyway I follow your advice and rewrite the code to use custom class type https://github.com/demas/listview_example/blob/master/App6/MainPage.xaml.cs. Sorry, but it doesn't works.  I tagged my question with 'windows-8.1' tag. Do you write about windows-8.1 modern UI apps? If you do, can you share your working solution?

Comment: I'm also using Windows 8.1, but WPF, not Windows Store Apps.